# Resultado inesperado na utilização do Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, multithreading

Seguinte, tenho uma classe que possui uma lista de string e a seguinte estrutura

```
public class Teste
{

      private List<string> _codigos;


      public void InsertDB(string[] files)
      {
          _codigos = new List<string>();

          Parallel.ForEach(files, file => Processa(file));

          Console.WriteLine(_codigos.Count);    
      }

      private static void Processa(string file)
      {    
           //Efetua um tratamento
           string resultado = "Obtem um resultado";
           _codigos.Add(resultado);    
      }
}
```

O Problema é o seguinte: se meu array **files** possui 7000 elementos, minha lista _codigos, deveria ter 7000 elementos. Só que isso não acontece, a cada vez que rodo o programa, a lista fica com 6989, 6957, 6899, etc.... Sempre um numero aleatório.

O interessante é, que quando substituo o **Parallel.ForEach()** por um simples **foreach()** como a seguir:

```
foreach(string file in files) {
    Processa(file);
}
```

Ai sim eu obtenho o resultado esperado, _codigos com 7000 elementos.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: O código real não é este, né? Ele tem um try-catch?

Comment: o código real não é esse, é só para exemplificar o problema. esse código ja demonstra o mesmo resultado que obtenho.

Comment: Outra coisa: por que usar o `Parallel.ForEach`?

Comment: porque o array files geralmente tem 2.000.000 de elementos. e fica muito mais rápido o processamento paralelo, utilizando todos os núcleos do processador.

Comment: Mas você não pode simplesmente adicionar itens numa lista de forma paralela. Existe todo um processo para se adicionar um item numa lista, obviamente fazer isso em paralelo vai causar problemas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List não é thread-safe, o que pode estar acontecendo é que em alguns casos duas threads vai tentar adicionar um item ao mesmo tempo, isso pode gerar algo inesperado (como adicionar apenas um objeto ou acontecer um exceção). No seu caso eu recomendo a utilização de ConcurrentBag:

```
var _codigos = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
```

ConcurrentBag é melhor porque ele utiliza bags internas que guardam o valor para cada thread e não faz o uso de `lock`, além de evitar o problema.

Answer (score 2):

Gabriel Coletta tem razão. `List` não é thread-safe.

Sempre que tem código em paralelo tentando escrever a uma estrutura só, tem que verificar que o código não conflita.

Um exemplo que mostra o cuidado que precisa ter é (isso será em C++, mais é simples):

```
void AdicionarNumero(int valorNovo)
{
    valorCompartilhado += valorNovo;
    return;
}
```

Se tem dois "threads" executando esta função em paralelo, pode ter problemas. O código `valorComparthilhado += valor;` talvez se torna os instruções:

1. Guardar valor de `valorNovo` num registro (memória no CPU).
2. Guardar valor de `valorCompartilhado` num registro.
3. Sumar os dois registros e guardar o resultado num registro.
4. Guardar a suma em `valorCompartilhado`.

Se os dois "threads" chegam a passo 3 ao mesmo tempo, os dois tem o mesmo valor de `valorCompartilhado` guardado. Então os dois fazem suma, um vai guardar o resultado, e depois o outro vai guardar o resultado. Isto quer dizer que um dos resultados será jogado fora.

Se não limitar este código a um "thread" a cada vez, não pode controlar o resultado. Se os dois "threads" chamam `AdicionarNumero` ao mesmo tempo com `valorCompartilhado == 5` e argumentos de `3` e `1`, pode ficar com resultados de `6`, `8`, ou `9` guardados em `valorCompartilhado`.

O jeito de limitar código para que só um "thread" pode entrar a cada vez é com um `lock` (como Gabriel Coletta comentou). Tambem pode usar uma estrutura e um algoritmo que não falha em paralelo, mesmo sem `lock` (como `ConcurrentBag`).

Comment: Desculpa se tem erros no meu português.